# How to pass Class.Companion as a parameter

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch, kotlin-companion

I have a function that needs to receive a Class.Companion as a parameter and the way I'm receiving it is as Class only and not Class.Companion

```
        fun <T: Any> input(text: String, type: KClass<T>? = null): T {
            val scanner= Scanner(System.`in`)
            while (true){
                print(text)
                val result = convertToAppropriateType(scanner.nextLine()) as T
                if(type == null) return result
                if(result::class == type){
                    return result
                }
            }
        }

InputUtils.input("", String)
```

I tried it as T and Class

Comment: Companions are just objects, they don't share a super class. So you would have your type as `Any` and pass it in as for example `MyClass`. However you can see the issue here, having `Any` type means function accepts anything, not only companions. That's why it'd be recommended to instead have a (marker) interface you implement on companions that are compatible with your function and use that as your type.

Comment: Trying to magically figure out the type of a String input is generally a bad plan.